# Extends Set's insert in swift for custom logic

Tags: swift

I need to have custom logic in a Set that defines when a Hashable can be insert or not.

First I tried to solve this with a observer

```
var Tenants: Set<Tenant> = [] {
    willSet {
        // to the business logic here
        // ...
```

But in an observer i can not return an error. So I tried to extend Set to overwrite the insert method.

```
extension Set where Element == Tenant {
    @inlinable mutating func insert(_ newMember: Element) -> (inserted: Bool, memberAfterInsert: Element){

        // .... do my logic here ...

        return (true, newMember)
    }
}
```

That works so far and the method will be called. I can return `true` and if my logic did not pass even a `false`. Ok, but how do I add the `Element` into the Set? `super.insert()`. The return is correct, but the Set is empty. How to add the elements into the concrete set?

Implementation so far

```
/// Global set of known tenants
var Tenants: Set<Tenant> = [] {
    willSet {
        let newTenants = newValue.symmetricDifference(Tenants)
        guard let newTenant = newTenants.first else {
            Logging.main.error("Can not find tenant to add.")
            return
        }
        Logging.main.info("Will add new Tenant \(newTenant.name) [\(newTenant.ident)]")
    }
}

extension Set where Element == Tenant {

    @inlinable mutating func insert(_ newMember: Element) -> (inserted: Bool, memberAfterInsert: Element){
        print("Check to add...")
        // .... do my logic here ...

        // ok
        return (true, newMember)
    }

}
```

The result is:

```
Check to add...
error : Can not find tenant to add.
Check to add...
error : Can not find tenant to add.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for "do my logic here"

```
    self = self.union([newMember])
```

Edit: Because this breaks the semantics of Set, I think it is better to write it as something like this:

```
struct CheckedSet<T: Hashable> {
    private(set) var wrappedSet: Set<T> = []

    var shouldInsert: (T) -> Bool = { _ in true }

    mutating func maybeInsert(_ t: T) {
        guard shouldInsert(t) else { return }
        wrappedSet.insert(t)
    }
}

var cs = CheckedSet<String>()
cs.shouldInsert = { str in str.allSatisfy(\.isLowercase) }

cs.maybeInsert("HELLO")
cs.wrappedSet  // []

cs.maybeInsert("hello")
cs.wrappedSet // ["hello"]
```

Comment: ... although I am not convinced this is a good idea, I think wrapping a private Set in a CheckedSet<T> struct with methods that are clear that the insert may not happen, is probably better semantically.  Like @Sweeper's answer

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with a property wrapper:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct TenantsSet {
    var wrappedSet: Set<Tenant>
    
    struct Projected {
        let error: Bool
    }
    
    var projectedValue = Projected(error: false)
    
    var wrappedValue: Set<Tenant> {
        get { wrappedSet }
        set {
            print("some custom logic")
            // set projectedValue appropriately
            wrappedSet = newValue
        }
    }
    
    init(wrappedValue: Set<Tenant>) {
        wrappedSet = wrappedValue
    }
}
```

This allows error-reporting by checking the `error` property on the projected value:

```
@TenantsSet var tenants = []

func f() {
    tenants = [Tenant()]
    if $tenants.error {
        
    }
}
```

As the [Swift Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html) says:

> Extensions add new functionality to an existing class, structure, enumeration, or protocol type.

You are not supposed to use them to modify existing behaviour. It would be very confusing to readers of your code. If you want to use an extension to do this, you should declare a new method, with a different signature. Perhaps call it `insert(newTenant:)`?

Comment: Agree to the discussion, but here overwrite existing functionality and not letting teammates using the class in another way is what is best suited I guess. Otherwise it’s possible to add the tenant anyway, that will lead to an complete other problem. But yes, fully agreed.

Comment: The property wrapper on the other side is a very cool thing that will be on the shortlist. Thanks a lot!!!